# Compare 2 Column values in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following content:

```
a|b|c
-+-+-
1|2|3
2|2|2
3|2|4
4|4|4
5|6|7
```

I want to check if all values in are same and print a message if so.
Example: Row 4,4,4 and 2,2,2 are having same column values. So I want to print "SAME" else print "Different"

How it can be done?

Comment: you did not accept the answer your previous question. Please do so if it was a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name, works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Use this. Note that `a=b and a=c` means also `b=c` so you need only two comparisons.

```
select a,b,c, case when (a=b and a=c) then 'SAME' else 'Different' end as print
from tableName
```

**EDIT:** The case when a, b, c are all `null`, is a different case. If you want the rows where all 3 values are `null` to be considered the same, you can add 
 `or (a is null and b is null and c is null)` or `or coalesce(a,b,c)is null`.
Like this:

```
select a,b,c, 
case when ((a=b and a=c) or(a is null and b is null and c is null)) then 'SAME' else 'Different' end as print
from tableName
```

OR

```
select a,b,c, 
case when ((a=b and a=c) or coalesce(a,b,c)is null) then 'SAME' else 'Different' end as print
from tableName
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple, non-NULL columns, then a pretty general way is:

```
select t.*,
       (case when least(a, b, c) = greatest(a, b, c) then 'SAME' else 'DIFFERENT' end) as flag
from t;
```

This easily generalizes to more columns.

Comment: good answer. Although the number of comparisons it is greater

Answer (score 1):

use case when

```
    select case when (a=b and a=c ) then 'same' else 'Different' end as output
from t
```

Comment: Will this run on Oracle?